# How is this String array bad in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, syntax-error, arrays

I took this right off of the internet from a well-reputed Java blogger. In a `Test.groovy` source file, I have:

```
void derp() {
    String[] toppings = {
        "Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"
    }
}
```

Syntax error:

> Groovy: unexpected token: Cheese @ line 16, column 4.

Line 16 is:

```
"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"
```

Column 4, I *believe* (although not sure exactly how the Groovy compiler counts cols) is the opening double-quote at the beginning of "Cheese". What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy doesn't have array literals, but you can use a list literal here. However, a list literal uses `[]`, not `{}`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Niederwieser (+1) - so like this: `String[] toppings = [ "Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives" ]`??? I thought that **any** valid Java was also valid Groovy...in hindsight that seems to be a false statement. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, like this. Most valid Java is valid Groovy. Your original snippet is neither valid Groovy nor valid Java.

Comment: Just wanted to add that array literal syntax doesn't work because with {} a closure is expected.  But `String[] toppings = ["Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"] as String[]` will work.

Comment: @JohnWagenleitner You don't need `as String[]` if you declare the type